# Redeploying NAR (node.js) archive with PM2

Tags: node.js, deployment, typescript, pm2

There is node.js app built with Typescript, so it needs to be first "compiled" to JS before it gets run. I'm planning to use NAR (https://github.com/h2non/nar) to build ready-to-deploy package to avoid fiddling with `npm install` and compiling it on production. I also use PM2 as process manager for node apps.

However as far as I know PM2 can only deploy from git (fetching sources and calling `npm install` etc. later on), but I couldnt find a way to easily deploy application that is already pre-built.

This is my `deploy.yml` file contained within archive that I extract with `nar extract <package>`:

```
apps:
  - script: dist/app.js
    merge_logs: true
    name: server
    instances: 1  # 0 => max, depending on CPU cores
    exec_mode: cluster
    node_args: --harmony --harmony_destructuring --harmony_default_parameters
    log_file: deploy/logs/server.log
    pid_file: deploy/pids/server.pid
    source_map_support: true
    env:
      NODE_ENV: production
```

It works fine when run for the first time, but then when I try to redeploy it (replacing application content with new version) and call `pm2 reload all` I get errored processes saying they either cannot load `ProcessManager` from PM2 or cannot find my `.env` file (which is in place).

As soon as I kill PM2 daemon with `pm2 kill` and start apps again with `pm2 start all deploy.yml` it clicks. But this is probably not how PM2 should be used, right?

Do you have any experience with such setup and had similar issues? Or maybe can you point me to another way of running my deployment?